# package does not exist error in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

In gradle file i have included 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0 but still error shows up

Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJava'.

> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `ActionBar` class or something else in the `android.support.v7.app` package. These are in the **appcompat-v7** library; to include it, make sure the **Android Support Repository** is installed in your **SDK Manager**, and put this in your module's **build.gradle** `dependencies` block:

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
```

Comment: 1 error: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Musicplayer2'.
> No signature of method: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.compile() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+]
Possible solutions: module(java.lang.Object)

Comment: You're adding it to the wrong build.gradle file. Add it to the one for your module, not the top-level one.